# Importing certain details from a 'txt' file

Tags: python, csv, file-read

I have a `.txt` file where names and addresses appear in the following format:

```
Sam, 35 Marly Road
...
...
```

I want to be able to search `Sam` and for `35 Marly Road` to come up.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
name = input("Please insert your required Client's name: ")
if name in open('clientAddress.txt').read():
  print ("Client Found")`
```

This checks if the ID inputted is available in the file, but it doesn't print the address. How do I change it, so it finds the name and prints the address?

Comment: I've tried:                                                                    open('clientRecords.txt').read():
    print (" Found Client")                                                                                                 But that only prints 'Found Client' and not the adress

Comment: Consider taking a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html combine reading the lines with an if statement that checks if it's the correct name and voila.

Comment: I don't need to check if it's the correct name- I've done that. I need my program to find the name in the file provided and print the address.

Comment: That's what I mean by: 'checking if it's the correct name'. You'll need an ìf`statement that checks if the line has the same name as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution - see below

```
username = input()

with open('clientRecords.txt', 'r') as clientsfile:
    for line in clientsfile.readline():
        if line.startswith("%s, " % username):
            print("Cient %s found: %s" % (username, line[len(username) + 2:]))
            break
```

Comment: I tried that- and it didn't do anything. No matter what i typed in, it simply terminated the program. (Skipped to the next line and gave me >>>)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
username = input()
with open('clientRecords.txt', 'r') as clientsfile:
    for line in clientsfile:
        if line.startswith("%s, " % username):
            print("Client %s found: %s" % (username, line.split(",")[1]))
            break
```

For loop iterates through file lines and when we found line starts with desired client name we print address and break loop.